# Module declared as X but was required as Y

Tags: go, go-modules, go-xorm

I'm trying to use `grafana/grafana/pkg/tsdb` package in my module.  I don't think this problem is specific to grafana but here it goes:

```sh
$ go get -u github.com/grafana/grafana/pkg/tsdb
go: finding github.com/inconshreveable/log15 latest
go: finding github.com/go-macaron/session latest
go: finding golang.org/x/oauth2 latest
go: finding github.com/teris-io/shortid latest
go: github.com/grafana/grafana/pkg/tsdb imports
        github.com/go-xorm/core: github.com/go-xorm/core@v0.6.3: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: xorm.io/core
                but was required as: github.com/go-xorm/core
```

It says that the package `tsdb` is importing xorm as `github.com/go-xorm/core`, but the module declares itself as `xorm.io/core`.

Looking at Grafana's [go.mod](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/go.mod#L29) file, it's using `github.com/go-xorm/core` and going to [github.com/go-xorm/core](https://github.com/go-xorm/core), it says the project is now archived... and it's [go.mod](https://github.com/go-xorm/core/blob/master/go.mod#L1) file indeed declared itself as `xorm.io/core`...

and suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit: I also had luck just using a slightly older version:

```
go get github.com/grafana/grafana/pkg/tsdb@6.6.1
```

---

I tried a replace, which can work sometimes:

```
module foo

replace github.com/go-xorm/core => xorm.io/core v0.6.2

go 1.13

require (
...
```

but I get a type error.

Luckily it looks like there is a PR out to fix this issue: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/22376

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It wasn't a problem for grafana b/c grafana vendor'ed in xorm/core library, and the version it vendored has the package name `github.com/go-xorm/core`.  Looks like xorm migrated their repos to gitea...

Comment: Your workaround (installing 6.6.1) does work BTW.  Thanks.  I've accepted the answer.